# Setting <support-screens android:normalScreens="false" /> still runs in Normal Screens

Tags: android, android-manifest

Can any one say how to solve this problem. Or it will automatically be made hidden from users in Google Play..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing abnormal.

```
Setting <support-screens android:normalScreens=“false” /> still runs in Normal Screens
```

If you defining `<supports-screen>` in your manifest then what going to happen is that in *Google Playstore* this application will not going to be *listed* if the requested device has normal screen size.